# Thank You Letter Report

Tags: civireport

How can I include the "Thank you Sent Date" filed in a report

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. You are more likely to get a useful response if you could provide a bit more detail in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, I am not seeing the "Thank you date" field as an option to be included in the built in reports, but you could do a find on contributions - if you export the primary fields, the thank you date ends up around column CC (might depend on what version of Civi you are using), or you can and select the relevant fields for export, the thank you date being one of them.

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Comment: This seems like an oversight, and one worth filing a bug report on.

Comment: Hey Jon—how can I file a bug report?

I'd love to have the option of including 'Thank-you Sent' as a column in CiviCRM's Contribution Reports.

Answer (score 1):

I had a client ask me about this recently, so I [submitted a patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13653) to add the thank-you dates to the Contribution Detail and Summary reports.  You can patch CiviCRM now; it will likely be part of CiviCRM 5.12 or 5.13.